# How to get ARN of an IAM role

Tags: terraform

I am creating 2 IAM roles in my main.tf that I will be creating at the same time. The first is main_role and the second is Backend_role.Backend_role is trusting main_role to assume its role and main_role also need policy that specify assume Backend_role.I have 2 questions
1... How do I reference the ARN of Backend_role in the resource policy section of main_role.
2... How do i reference the ARN  of main_role in the assume_role_policy resource section of Backend_role

```
main.tf

resource "aws_iam_role" "main_role" {
  name = var.role_name

}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "main_policy"{
  name = "sts-assume-roles"
  role = aws_iam_role.main_role.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "sts:AssumeRole"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        ${How do i reference the ARN of the Backend_role}
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "Backend_role" {
  name = var.bakend_role_name

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS":"How do i reference the ARN of main_role"
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Condition": {}
  }
}
EOF 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Role ARNs always have the form `arn:aws:iam::{account number}:role/{role name}`.

If you're creating two roles that reference each other, you should template out the ARNS rather than referencing the resources directly. This avoids a circular reference.

You can get your account number like this:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
```

and you can template it in like this:

```
"arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/${var.my_role_name}"
```

You also might want to clean up that code - the <<EOF in the first statement looks unclosed, and the backend role variable is spelled bakend_role_name.

Comment: so i can not use  "aws_iam_role.main_role.arn" and  "aws_iam_role.backend_role.arn"?

Comment: You can use that in the backend, but if the main role then references the backend as  `aws_iam_role.Backend_role.arn`, you have a circular reference. The main role can't be built until the backend role is, and the backend can't be built until the main role is.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear in my question..my question is .can i use aws_iam_role.Backend_role.arn in main role  and can i use aws_iam_role.main_role.arn in backend role?

Comment: You can't use both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.How can I reference their respective ARN if i don't want to use data "aws_caller_identity" "current"

Comment: will it work if i use aws_iam_role.Backend_role.arn in main role and then use "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/${var.main_role_name }" in backend. or can i just use data "aws_caller_identity" "current" in both and reference their respective variables?

Comment: If one references the other, it's not a circular reference. It might be better to template the arn for both for consistency's sake.